# React context not passing the value

Tags: reactjs

A problem while using react context method
I am trying to make a translation switch of navbar and on selecting a specific language from dropdown of the switch I need to pass a value to the rendering page using react context , for translation I used react translate,but after writing code the value of selected language is not able to pass to selectedLanguage by assistant of react context method but I am not able to do it. I dont getting idea how to pass the value to selectedLanguage.

switch.js :-

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import '../index.css'
//exporting l;anguage context
export const LanguageContext = React.createContext();

const LanguageSwitcherx = () => {
  
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState('en');
  const languageOptions = [
    { label: 'ENGLISH', value: 'en' },
    { label: 'മലയാളം', value: 'ml' },
    { label: 'हिंदी', value: 'hi' },
    { label: 'Français', value: 'fr' },
  ];

  const handleLanguageChange = (event) => {
    setLanguage(event.target.value);
    console.log(setLanguage)
  };
console.log(language)
  const [showLanguageSwitcher, setShowLanguageSwitcher] = useState(false);

  const toggleLanguageSwitcher = () => {
    setShowLanguageSwitcher(!showLanguageSwitcher);
  };

  return (
    //value assigned for context
    <LanguageContext.Provider value={language}>
    <div className="language-switcher">
      {showLanguageSwitcher ? (
        <div>
          <select value={language} onChange={handleLanguageChange}>
            {languageOptions.map((option) => (
              <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
                {option.label}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
          <button onClick={toggleLanguageSwitcher}></button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={toggleLanguageSwitcher}>诶</button>
      )}
    </div>
    </LanguageContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default LanguageSwitcherx;
```

rendering page where value of selected language need to be updated :-

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import translate from "translate";
//import context
import { LanguageContext } from './TranslateSwitch'

const Newsitem = (props) => {
  const { title, description, imageUrl, newsUrl, date, key} = props;
  const [showDescription, setShowDescription] = useState(false);
  const [translatedTitle, setTranslatedTitle] = useState("");
  const [translatedDescription, setTranslatedDescription] = useState("");
  //context
  const selectedLanguage = useContext(LanguageContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(selectedLanguage);
    const translateTitleAndDescription = async () => {
      const [translatedTitle, translatedDescription] = await Promise.all([
        translate(title, { to: selectedLanguage }),
        translate(description, { to: selectedLanguage }),
      ]);
      setTranslatedTitle(translatedTitle);
      setTranslatedDescription(translatedDescription);
    };
    translateTitleAndDescription();
  }, [title, description, selectedLanguage]);

  const handleReadMore = () => {
    setShowDescription(!showDescription);
  };

  return (
    <div key={key} className='my-3'>
      <div className='card' style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
        <img src={imageUrl} className='card-img-top' alt='...' />
        <div className='card-body'>
          <h5 className='card-title'>{translatedTitle || title}</h5>
          {showDescription && (
            <p className='card-text'>
              {translatedDescription || description}
            </p>
          )}
          <p className='card-text'>
            <small className='text-muted'>{date}</small>
          </p>
          <button
            className='btn btn-sm btn-dark'
            onClick={handleReadMore}
          >
            {showDescription ? 'Read Less' : 'Read More'}
          </button>
          <a
            rel='noreferrer'
            href={newsUrl}
            target='_blank'
            className='btn btn-sm btn-dark ms-2'
          >
            Read Full Article
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Newsitem;
```

my github :- https://github.com/itsdlhqcp/Hot-Paper.git

I need to change the value of selected language to fr as per selection from the drop down switch

Comment: the link given in the repo is working as intended

Answer (score 0):

The context should be on higher level. You need to wrap the provider on the component that need to access the value. (usually wrap on the whole app, depends on your situation)

for example:

```
//parent component
const YourContext = createContext()

<>
  <YourContext.Provider>
     <ComponentA /> // can get the value from the context
     <ComponentB /> // can get the value from the context
  </YourContext.Provider>
  <ComponentC /> // can NOT get the value from the context
</>
```